# Small picture of code on the side of IDE

Tags: visual-studio

I have no idea what this feature is called, but in sublime text, you can see a small picture of your code at the side of the screen

[image]

Does Visual studio have a similar  feature? If so, how do you enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called map mode you can change it in the scroll bar options to show annotations scroll bar, it is very useful for checking for errors in code.

Comment: Other usefullness: also shows highlight reference results and breakpoints, and if you install GitDiffMargin, highly recommended, it shows annotations of where code has been modified compared to HEAD. Couldn't live without that anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called "map mode" scroll bar. Simply type the word in the quick navigator. Ctrl-Q